# Encryption alert (Alert (21))from the Server and connection resets

Tags: ssl, alert, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

1. I am working on TLS 1.2  Cipher TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, After send the application data server throw an error message Encryption alert (21).
2. I observed on the wire shark[image] log there is no Finish packet from the client even though server starts next communication.
   Please give me the support. Thanks advance.

Comment: Wireshark can't decrypt encrypted packets unless you give it the session secret(s), or for old-style plain-RSA keyexchange (not applicable here) the server privatekey. And in 1.2 GCM suites the first record after CCS (which is handshake record containing Finished) starts with 8 bytes of IV for which many implementations use/duplicate the seqnum which is zero (as 8 bytes), which wireshark falsely decodes as two 'Hello Request' messages (each 00 00 00 00). If the IV is nonzero wireshark decoding fails entirely and it gives up and displays 'Encrypted Handshake Message'.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I am working on Microchip CY920 act as client. Any possible way to decrypt a wire shark log?

Comment: Only if you provide an appropriate secret (for 1.2, the premaster secret or master secret) from one of the endpoints. I have no clue what Microchip CY920 is, but if you could get at its internals you probably wouldn't be trying to use a wireshark capture; similarly I don't know anything about the server, but if you controlled it you wouldn't be asking this; so, no. The purpose of a secure protocol is to prevent eavesdropping or tampering/forgery by unauthorized parties, and you seem to be unauthorized. Plus you've not said how it's programming or development.

Comment: Using Microchip CY920 I developed a client using the C program. I have my own client certificates , premaster and master secret key. I read some option available in wire shark using the private key we able to decrypt a packet. I try that method I am not able to any decrypted data. Still that was encrypted. Thank you for your support. I am going to try some other method.

Comment: (0) if you're writing the client you have the clear data, why do you need to decrypt it? (1) as I said before, wireshark can use the _server_ privatekey to decrypt _if your ciphersuite uses plain-RSA keyexchange_, but in your case you are using a ciphersuite that uses DHE-RSA keyexchange NOT plain-RSA so that option doesn't work in your case.

Comment: Yes, Understood now.